# javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Not a relative path

Tags: aem, jcr

while accessing the node i am getting following error:

javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Not a relative path

i am newbie to AEM CQ5.i tried to google it. did not found any description about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to access the JCR via java program? Or when you are able to see this error. Can you provide some more details what you are doing?

Comment: Pls read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @VAr yes i am trying to access JCR via java program. i want to upload a image to my DAM from a URL. i am getting this error when i try to access my DAM path "content/DAM/images"

Comment: It should be **/content/DAM/images**. Any of the `content/dam/images` or `./content/dam/images` will give _Not an absolute path exception_.  A good example can be found at [helpx.adobe.com](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/uploading-files-aem1.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you get a Node from the session object you have to use '/'

```
session.getNode( "/MyFolder" );
```

But if you use the root node you have to write

```
session.getRootNode().getNode( "MyFolder" );
```

Answer (score 1):

//Remove the first / char - JCR API does not like that

```
    String newPath = path.replaceFirst("/", "");
```

//USE JCR API TO get the Asset Data so we can move it to another JCR location

```
    Node root = session.getRootNode(); 
    Node fileNode = root.getNode(newPath);
```